# Frama-C \strlen function

Tags: c, string, strlen, frama-c

I installed Frama-C Sodium (20150201) + the Jessie plugin, and I'm trying to reproduce the examples provided in the ACSL reference manual. But I can't use Jessie library functions (like `\strlen`)  because every time I use one of them, I get errors such as:

```
[kernel] user error: unbound function \strlen in annotation.
```

This is the code:

```
/*@
      requires \base_addr(src) != \base_addr(dest);
      requires \strlen(src) >= 0;
*/
char *strcpy ( char * dest , const char * src );
```

Launching `frama-c` from bash (with `-jessie` option) has no effect.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `char *strcpy()`? The function returns the pointer you passed for `*dest`.

Comment: @Olaf: \strlen in this context is used to check if src points to valid a C-string.
Yes, it returns a char *. Typo fixed.

Comment: So it is not the C function of the same name? Irritating to use the same name.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how \strlen checks for a valid C-string, its only argument is a pointer.

Comment: @WeatherVane logic functions in ACSL need not be computable. If you waive this requirement, it is easy to write a definition of `\strlen` using a `\forall` quantification over all the characters after the pointer argument.

Comment: @Olaf How is `\strlen` the same name as any C function? It was specifically chosen because it could not clash, for obvious lexical reasons, with any standard or program-specific C variable name.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: You should know that backslash is no valid character for a C identifier (and I strongly assume it is not for Frama-C, but more of a tag), so obviously I refer to the identifer part only. Using the same identifer as for a simliar function in the target language is just a bad idea from a psychological sight: same name == same semantics is a matter of association. Here it seems to be different semantics. While that is not much of a problem for different contexts/files/languages, here it actually can be easier confused.

Comment: @Olaf \ is part of the name `\strlen`. The fact that it is an invalid character to use for a C identifier is entirely according to plan; indeed, `\strlen` is not a C identifier.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: as that is laready in a comment, there is extremly little chance the compiler would take it for an identifier anyway (even if, the backslash would not necessarily keep it from doing). Anyway, thanks for the infos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic function `\strlen` is currently not supported by the Frama-C implementation. If you download the [ACSL 1.9 (Sodium implementation)](http://frama-c.com/download/acsl-implementation-Sodium-20150201.pdf)  manual, you will see that the definition is in red, meaning it is not supported.

Instead, you can try replacing `\strlen` by the function `strlen`, whose axiomatic definition is given in the file `libc/__fc_string_axiomatic.h` of your Frama-C installation. To do so, make sure to add `#include <string.h>` at the beginning of your example. (`string.h` automatically includes `__fc_string_axiomatic.h`)

I reproduce below the beginning of the axiomatic block `StrLen` that defines `strlen`:

```
  @ axiomatic StrLen {
  @ logic ℤ strlen{L}(char *s);
  @ // reads s[0..];
  @
  @ axiom strlen_pos_or_null{L}:
  @   \forall char* s; \forall ℤ i;
  @      (0 <= i
  @       && (\forall ℤ j; 0 <= j < i ==> s[j] != '\0')
  @       && s[i] == '\0') ==> strlen(s) == i;
  @
  @ axiom strlen_neg{L}:
  @   \forall char* s;
  @      (\forall ℤ i; 0 <= i ==> s[i] != '\0')
  @      ==> strlen(s) < 0;
```

Most of the definitions of the file `__fc_string_axiomatic.h` were originally written for Jessie, so you should be able to prove your specification of `strcpy` -- if you provide a loop invariant that is strong enough.

You may also be interested in the document [ACSL by example](https://www.fokus.fraunhofer.de/download/acsl_by_example), that specifies and proves some common functions.